# Prevent Vue from submitting all forms in page

Tags: php, vue.js

I have two forms, register-form and pay-form, in one page and each of them has their own submit button but when I click one, it submits both forms.

Each of the forms has a submit button that looks like this

**Register.php**

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary mb-3" 
  @submit.prevent="register"
  :disabled="registerForm.busy"
  name="register-billing">
</button>
```

**Pay.php**

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary mb-3" 
  @submit.prevent="post"
  :disabled="registerForm.busy"
  name="register-billing">
</button>
```

I have tried

```
@click.prevent="register"
```

and

```
v-on:click.stop="register"
```

with no luck

How can I prevent both forms from submitting and only submit a form that its button was clicked?

Comment: maybe you put them inside a  single <form> tag

Comment: You attached a `submit` handler to `<button>`, which does not have a `submit` event. That handler should be on `<form>`.

Comment: @Siya if my answer helped you, could you accept it for future readers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the form element you can set a `@submit.prevent="doSomething()"` to run a function when a button is clicked inside the form.

You can also set the button to `type="button"` which will stop it from submitting the form. By default, any button in a `<form>` tag will submit unless you define its type.

As shown below.

```
<form @submit.prevent="doSomething()">
...
<button type="button">Does Nothing</button>
<button type="submit">Submits the form by calling doSomething().</button>
<button>Submits the form by calling doSomething().</button>
</form>
```

```
<form>
...
<button type="button" @click="doSomething()">Only runs the function, does not submit the form.</button>
</form>
```